Wgpu egui interconnection
I am trying to add an egui/eframe ui to my wgpu application. I can tessellate the current context and get a description of the vertices, but I cannot find a way to actually render these.
For instance, I can easily render the following vertex in my shader by using the color information:
Vertex { pos: [0.5 0.5], uv: [0.0 0.0], color: Color32([27, 27, 27, 255]) }

But when adding a ui.heading, I get vertices with uv coordinates, but I have no idea which texture nor position/scale that egui is using.
Vertex { pos: [94.0 14.0], uv: [0.4 0.3], color: Color32([140, 140, 140, 255]) },
Vertex { pos: [85.0 28.0], uv: [0.4 0.5], color: Color32([140, 140, 140, 255]) },
Vertex { pos: [94.0 28.0], uv: [0.4 0.5], color: Color32([140, 140, 140, 255]) }

How can I render these egui "descriptions" in my own application? Is there any detailed documentation on how to approach this task?
Note: I looked at egui-wgpu crate, but I cannot find examples that work with newest versions of wgpu/egui (seems there have been multiple API breaking changes). I would love to use existing libraries, provided they work and allow enough control.
